# Can't be able to read Cocoabuilder file in Cocos2d

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, ios7

I am trying to create scene using Cocobuilder. which i created successful. but i am getting an error when using ccbi file in xcode.

I am getting this error.

```
CCBReader: Incompatible ccbi file version (file: 3 reader: 5)
```

I am using Xcode 5 & CocoaBulder 2.1. also Download updated `CCBReader` Class form GIT

Comment: obviously a file version mismatch, either update cocos builder or use a matching version of CCBReader

Comment: can you please tell me how do i get appropriate version of CCBReader?

Comment: http://cocosbuilder.com/?page_id=11

Comment: I am having latest version of cocobuilder which is 2.1 & also download updated CCBReader version yet i have same error.

Comment: Did you use the CCBReader from the corresponding v2.1 examples archive? http://www.cocosbuilder.com/downloads/CocosBuilder-2.1-examples.zip

Comment: I run that example which was working nicely. but if i add same file then i am getting this error. even if i creating new project.

Comment: weird, they ought to be matching. You are using cocos2d-iphone v2.1 as well? The v3 preview comes with ccbreader already integrated but that is for SpriteBuilder, not CocosBuilder.

Comment: yes i think its problem with CCBReader version. so can you please suggests me CCBReader version for Cocoabuilder 2.1 & Cocos2d-v2.1 in xcode5.

Comment: In the examples project is a folder named "Add to your project" which contains the correct CCBReader version. I just checked, its reader version is 3, not 5, so this is the matching CCBReader for CocosBuilder v2.1. I suppose you did not add this exact version of CCBReader to your project.

Comment: I tried that but its throwing so many errors.